# include intellij modules of the project to gitignore

Tags: git, intellij-idea, version-control

I have multimodule maven project and I want to include .iml and .idea files which IntelliJ creates for all the modules to my .gitignore. My app structure is as follows:

```
root/  

.gitignore

/module1

/module2
```

and the content of the .gitignore is as foolows:

```
# User-specific stuff:
*/.idea/workspace.xml
*/.idea/tasks.xml
*/.idea/dictionaries
*/.idea/vcs.xml
*/.idea/jsLibraryMappings.xml

# Sensitive or high-churn files:
*/.idea/dataSources.ids
*/.idea/dataSources.xml
*/.idea/dataSources.local.xml
*/.idea/sqlDataSources.xml
*/.idea/dynamic.xml
*/.idea/uiDesigner.xml

#MAC OS
.DS_Store

#Intellij
*/target/
*/out/
*.iml
*/.idea/


#Properties
*/*.properties

#IntelliJ
*/out/
*/target/



## File-based project format:
*.iws

## Plugin-specific files:


# mpeltonen/sbt-idea plugin
.idea_modules/
```

however git still show all the files within .idea folders as untracked

Could you please help with that?

Answer (score 1):

Try to change `*/.idea/` to `**/.idea/`.